# Data List get data with HTTPSERVICE

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm building an XML generated Data list.

I built Data List with Flash Catalyst. Now I'm trying to bind the data that I'm receiving via HTTPService to my DataList.

All the ways that I saw on some websites - i think isn't right.

in 1 datalist item I have several text fields.

the initial way how I though to do this and imagined to do this was to put all data in the array, and then call them 1 by 1.

SomemyArray.title
SomemyArray.description
SomemyArray.date
SomemyArray.link

I'm not a master in Flex, I'm yet playing around with different things in Flex..

So maybe you can tell me how it should be done properly.

Here's the project.. You won't see the display 'cuz it's broken, but I have enabled View Source, so you can take a look at the source: [The Link](http://cgclient.net/datalist/Main.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your result format to e4x, so your HTTPService looks like this:

```
<s:HTTPService id="service" url="rss20.xml" result="service_resultHandler(event)"
                  fault="service_faultHandler(event)" resultFormat="e4x"/>
```

By default even XML files are downloaded with a text format.